# Oreo 8.1 - Trouble enabling ADB for system by modifying /system/build.prop in TWRP adb shell

Tags: adb, 8.1-oreo

I've followed https://gist.github.com/varhub/7b9555cdd1e5ad785ffde2300fcfd0bd and have doublechecked that the build.prop is indeed modified i.e. system was mounted in read-write mode.

Unfortunately after reboots, the /data/property/persist.sys.usb.config resets itself to just mtp (instead of mtp,adb).

Any ideas what I am missing? I have to do this via adb since I am working on a headless phone with a broken screen (touch/display not working at all).

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get past this conventionally and no answers here either. I installed a LineageOS based rom via TWRP commandline and managed to get it to boot. It has ADB enabled by default and I was able to inject the adb key via the TWRP shell too.

Now I am stuck at a different problem of adding and connecting to a WiFi SSID via the commandline.

Comment: You can just supply a `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file with the right credentials and enable wifi using `svc wifi enable`.

Comment: @Zulakis I have already tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work on my setup. I've raised a new question at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200285/connecting-wifi-via-adb-shell-oreo-8-1-lineageos

Waiting patiently for new things to try.

Comment: You could probably edit the `/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.qcom.usb.rc` file to achieve what you want. (That's what I did for a similar issue).