# Connecting to WiFi via ADB Shell

Tags: wi-fi, adb, shell, broken-screen, wpa-supplicant

I've tried all publicly discussed methods I could find to connect to WiFi via ADB on a phone with a broken screen (no display/no touch). The closest I have got is via `wpa_cli` using the method #1 described below.

Other methods that I tried are also mentioned but with no success. My goal for this broken phone is to use it as a headless server either via LinuxDeploy or native apps for Android, and for that I need to get VNC running and for that I need to connect to Wifi somehow.

Solutions for connecting to Wifi OR otherwise getting VNC access to the Android display (using ADB usb only) are welcome. I don't have a USB-C Network card so using that isn't an option at this stage.

#### Method #1 - Using WPA_CLI

In this case I leave /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf and /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml untouched and just pop into `wpa_cli` using `adb shell`

#### wpa_cli Setup

```
> add_network
0
> set_network 0 scan_ssid 1
OK
> set_network 0 ssid "my_ssid"
OK
> set_network 0 key_mgmt WPA-PSK
OK
> set_network 0 psk "my_wifi_pass"
OK
> enable_network 0
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>Trying to associate with SSID 'fy-huawei-m9'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=5 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=6 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=fy-huawei-m9
<3>Associated with 50:01:d9:41:d7:00
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=7 BSSID=50:01:d9:41:d7:00 SSID=fy-huawei-m9
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=8 BSSID=50:01:d9:41:d7:00 SSID=fy-huawei-m9
<3>WPA: Key negotiation completed with 50:01:d9:41:d7:00 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 50:01:d9:41:d7:00 completed [id=0 id_str=]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=9 BSSID=50:01:d9:41:d7:00 SSID=fy-huawei-m9
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=50:01:d9:41:d7:00 reason=3 locally_generated=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=0 state=0 BSSID=50:01:d9:41:d7:00 SSID=fy-huawei-m9
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
```

Looks like the wifi interface associates momentarily with the SSID but then immediately disconnects.

Logcat Output

```
01-01 00:16:25.358  1074  1913 D WifiService: setWifiEnabled: true pid=2849, uid=0, package=com.android.shell
01-01 00:16:25.358  1074  1913 I WifiService: setWifiEnabled package=com.android.shell uid=0 enable=true
01-01 00:16:25.362   756   756 I android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Wifi HAL started
01-01 00:16:25.371   756   756 I android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Wifi driver is ready: Success
01-01 00:16:25.625   756   756 I WifiHAL : Initializing wifi
01-01 00:16:25.625   951   963 I LOWI-8.5.0.3.a: [LOWIController] isWifiEnabled: Wifi is now enabled
01-01 00:16:25.635   756   756 I WifiHAL : mpdu_size_threshold : 128, aggressive_statistics_gathering : 0
01-01 00:16:25.636  1074  1675 I WifiVendorHal: Vendor Hal started successfully
01-01 00:16:25.636  1074  1675 D WificondControl: Setting up driver for client mode
01-01 00:16:25.770  1074  1675 D WifiStateMachine: Setting OUI to DA-A1-19
01-01 00:16:25.772   756   756 E WifiHAL : wifi_set_scanning_mac_oui: requestResponse Error:-1
01-01 00:16:25.774  1074  1675 E WifiVendorHal: setScanningMacOui(l.1445) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown}
01-01 00:16:25.784  1074  1675 I WifiVendorHal: Driver: 5.1.1.28U Firmware: FW:1.0.0.133.0 HW:WCN3990_V2.1
01-01 00:16:25.799  1074  1110 I WifiService: requestActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:16:25.799  1074  1110 I WifiService: reportActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:16:25.799  1074  1110 I WifiService: getSupportedFeatures uid=1000
01-01 00:16:25.835  1074  1675 D WifiConnectivityHelper: Firmware supported feature set: 48931bf
01-01 00:16:25.836  1074  1677 I WifiScanningService: wifi driver loaded with scan capabilities: max buckets=6
01-01 00:16:25.840  1074  1675 D WifiConnectivityHelper: Firmware roaming supported with capabilities: max num blacklist bssid=16 max num whitelist ssid=4
01-01 00:16:25.841  1074  1675 D WifiNative-wlan0: configureRoaming
01-01 00:16:25.842  1074  1675 I WifiStateMachine: disconnectedstate enter
01-01 00:16:25.844  1074  1675 D WifiStateMachine: resetting EAP-SIM/AKA/AKA' networks since SIM was changed
01-01 00:16:25.844  1074  1675 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) WifiStateMachin identical 2 lines
01-01 00:16:25.845  1074  1675 D WifiStateMachine: resetting EAP-SIM/AKA/AKA' networks since SIM was changed
01-01 00:16:25.854  1074  1110 I WifiService: requestActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:16:25.854  1074  1110 I WifiService: reportActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:16:25.854  1074  1110 I WifiService: getSupportedFeatures uid=1000
01-01 00:16:25.939  1835  1973 I QCNEJ/CndHalConnector: -> SND notifyWifiP2pStateChanged(5)
01-01 00:16:55.456  1074  1913 D WifiService: setWifiEnabled: true pid=2876, uid=0, package=com.android.shell
01-01 00:16:55.456  1074  1913 I WifiService: setWifiEnabled package=com.android.shell uid=0 enable=true
01-01 00:17:35.524  1074  1110 I WifiService: requestActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:17:35.524  1074  1110 I WifiService: reportActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:17:35.525  1074  1110 I WifiService: getSupportedFeatures uid=1000
01-01 00:19:35.647   756  2865 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x6a
01-01 00:19:36.272   756  2865 I WifiHAL : event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0x6b
01-01 00:19:36.441  1074  1675 W WifiConfigManager: Looking up network with invalid networkId -1
01-01 00:19:36.442  1074  1675 W WifiStateMachine: Connected to unknown networkId -1, disconnecting...
01-01 00:19:37.260   756  2865 E WifiHAL : Few pkt stats messages missed: rcvd = 0, prev = 0
01-01 00:19:37.260   756  2865 I WifiHAL : Fate Tx-Rx: Packet fate stats stop received
01-01 00:19:58.058  1074  1110 I WifiService: requestActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:19:58.058  1074  1110 I WifiService: reportActivityInfo uid=1000
01-01 00:19:58.059  1074  1110 I WifiService: getSupportedFeatures uid=1000
```

The key line here are:

```
01-01 00:19:36.441  1074  1675 W WifiConfigManager: Looking up network with invalid networkId -1
01-01 00:19:36.442  1074  1675 W WifiStateMachine: Connected to unknown networkId -1, disconnecting...
```

Looks like the WifiConfigManager won't let me connect to a network which isn't defined in /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml

### Method #2 - Naive definition in wpa_supplicant.conf

In this attempt I simply define the entwork in wpa_supplicant.conf and don't touch /data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml

Here is what my wpa_supplicant.conf looks like:

#### wpa_supplicant.conf

```
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=DIR=/data/system/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wifi
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=1
fast_reauth=1

network={
    ssid="my_ssid"
    psk="my_wifi_pass"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=241
}
```

I then proceed to disable and re-enable the wifi service using `svc wifi disable` and `svc wifi enable`, and even reboot the phone but in both cases it doesn't seem to even attempt connecting to the network. The `invalid networkId -1` message still pops up.

#### Logcat Output:

```
01-01 00:00:06.649  1062  1062 D WifiService: resetting networks because SIM was removed
01-01 00:00:06.649  1062  1062 D WifiService: resetting country code because SIM is removed
01-01 00:00:06.649  1062  1062 D WifiService: resetting networks because SIM was removed
01-01 00:00:06.649  1062  1062 D WifiService: resetting country code because SIM is removed
01-01 00:00:06.649  1062  1670 D WifiStateMachine: resetting EAP-SIM/AKA/AKA' networks since SIM was changed
01-01 00:00:06.650  1062  1670 D WifiStateMachine: resetting EAP-SIM/AKA/AKA' networks since SIM was changed
01-01 00:00:07.055  1062  1073 D WificondControl: Scan result ready event
01-01 00:00:07.061  1062  1670 W WifiConfigManager: Looking up network with invalid networkId -1
```

### Method #3 - Copying WifiConfigStore.xml from a different phone connecting to this SSID

As a last ditch attempt, I restored the original wpa_supplicant.conf and copied over WifiConfigStore.xml from a phone running the same Android version that successfully connects to the WiFi network in question. Then I rebooted the phone

#### WifiConfigStore.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<WifiConfigStoreData>
    <int name="Version" value="1" />
    <NetworkList>
        <Network>
            <WifiConfiguration>
                <string name="ConfigKey">&quot;fy-huawei-m9&quot;WPA_PSK</string>
                <string name="SSID">&quot;fy-huawei-m9&quot;</string>
                <null name="BSSID" />
                <string name="PreSharedKey">&quot;THEFORTUNE&quot;</string>
                <null name="WEPKeys" />
                <int name="WEPTxKeyIndex" value="0" />
                <boolean name="HiddenSSID" value="false" />
                <boolean name="RequirePMF" value="false" />
                <byte-array name="AllowedKeyMgmt" num="1">02</byte-array>
                <byte-array name="AllowedProtocols" num="1">0b</byte-array>
                <byte-array name="AllowedAuthAlgos" num="1">01</byte-array>
                <byte-array name="AllowedGroupCiphers" num="1">0f</byte-array>
                <byte-array name="AllowedPairwiseCiphers" num="1">06</byte-array>
                <boolean name="Shared" value="true" />
                <int name="Status" value="0" />
                <null name="FQDN" />
                <null name="ProviderFriendlyName" />
                <null name="LinkedNetworksList" />
                <null name="DefaultGwMacAddress" />
                <boolean name="ValidatedInternetAccess" value="true" />
                <boolean name="NoInternetAccessExpected" value="false" />
                <int name="UserApproved" value="0" />
                <boolean name="MeteredHint" value="false" />
                <int name="MeteredOverride" value="0" />
                <boolean name="UseExternalScores" value="false" />
                <int name="NumAssociation" value="22" />
                <int name="CreatorUid" value="1000" />
                <string name="CreatorName">android.uid.system:1000</string>
                <string name="CreationTime">time=08-02 08:39:20.369</string>
                <int name="LastUpdateUid" value="1000" />
                <string name="LastUpdateName">android.uid.system:1000</string>
                <int name="LastConnectUid" value="1000" />
                <boolean name="IsLegacyPasspointConfig" value="false" />
                <long-array name="RoamingConsortiumOIs" num="0" />
            </WifiConfiguration>
            <NetworkStatus>
                <string name="SelectionStatus">NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLED</string>
                <string name="DisableReason">NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLE</string>
                <string name="ConnectChoice">&quot;fy-net-ac&quot;WPA_PSK</string>
                <long name="ConnectChoiceTimeStamp" value="1534074466002" />
                <boolean name="HasEverConnected" value="true" />
            </NetworkStatus>
            <IpConfiguration>
                <string name="IpAssignment">DHCP</string>
                <string name="ProxySettings">NONE</string>
            </IpConfiguration>
        </Network>
    </NetworkList>
    <PasspointConfigData>
        <long name="ProviderIndex" value="0" />
    </PasspointConfigData>
</WifiConfigStoreData>
```

#### wpa_supplicant.conf

```
01-01 00:00:05.424  1073  1637 D WifiConfigStore: Reading from user store completed in 4 ms.
01-01 00:00:05.440  1073  1637 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 16 ms.
01-01 00:00:05.440  1073  1637 D WIFI    : got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=6, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.442  1073  1637 D WifiConnectivityHelper: Firmware supported feature set: 48931bf
01-01 00:00:05.442  1073  1637 D WifiConnectivityHelper: Firmware roaming supported with capabilities: max num blacklist bssid=16 max num whitelist ssid=4
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WifiNative-wlan0: configureRoaming
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WIFI    : got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=3, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WIFI    : got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=9, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WIFI    : got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WIFI_UT : got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=6, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WIFI_UT : got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=3, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WIFI_UT : got request NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=9, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.443  1073  1637 D WIFI_UT : got request NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ] with score 0
01-01 00:00:05.445  1073  1676 I SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: Registering ISupplicant service ready callback.
01-01 00:00:05.447  1073  1689 I SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: IServiceNotification.onRegistration for: android.hardware.wifi.supplicant@1.0::ISupplicant, default preexisting=true
01-01 00:00:05.447  1073  1689 I zygote64: Looking for service android.hardware.wifi.supplicant@1.0::ISupplicant/default
01-01 00:00:05.449  1073  1689 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering getInterface()
01-01 00:00:05.449  1073  1689 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: getInterface() completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.449  1073  1689 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving getInterface() with result = android.hardware.wifi.supplicant@1.0::ISupplicantP2pIface@Proxy
01-01 00:00:05.450  1073  1689 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering registerCallback()
01-01 00:00:05.450  1073  1689 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: registerCallback() completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.450  1073  1689 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving registerCallback()
01-01 00:00:05.450  1073  1689 I SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: Completed initialization of ISupplicant interfaces.
01-01 00:00:05.484  1073  1632 I WifiService: getConfiguredNetworks uid=1000
01-01 00:00:05.543  1073  1073 D WifiService: resetting networks because SIM was removed
01-01 00:00:05.543  1073  1073 D WifiService: resetting country code because SIM is removed
01-01 00:00:05.543  1073  1637 D WifiStateMachine: resetting EAP-SIM/AKA/AKA' networks since SIM was changed
01-01 00:00:05.544  1073  1073 D WifiService: resetting networks because SIM was removed
01-01 00:00:05.544  1073  1073 D WifiService: resetting country code because SIM is removed
01-01 00:00:05.544  1073  1637 D WifiStateMachine: resetting EAP-SIM/AKA/AKA' networks since SIM was changed
01-01 00:00:05.556  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering setWpsDeviceName(Android_d3d3)
01-01 00:00:05.556  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: setWpsDeviceName(Android_d3d3) completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.556  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving setWpsDeviceName(Android_d3d3)
01-01 00:00:05.556  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering setSsidPostfix(-Android_d3d3)
01-01 00:00:05.557  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: setSsidPostfix(-Android_d3d3) completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.557  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving setSsidPostfix(-Android_d3d3)
01-01 00:00:05.557  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering setWpsDeviceType(10-0050F204-5)
01-01 00:00:05.557  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: setWpsDeviceType(10-0050F204-5) completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.558  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving setWpsDeviceType(10-0050F204-5)
01-01 00:00:05.558  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering setWpsConfigMethods(virtual_push_button physical_display keypad)
01-01 00:00:05.558  1847  1956 I QCNEJ/CndHalConnector: -> SND notifyWifiP2pStateChanged(5)
01-01 00:00:05.559  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: setWpsConfigMethods(virtual_push_button physical_display keypad) completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.559  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving setWpsConfigMethods(virtual_push_button physical_display keypad)
01-01 00:00:05.559  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering getDeviceAddress()
01-01 00:00:05.559  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: getDeviceAddress() completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.560  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving getDeviceAddress() with result = 82:ad:16:7a:57:57
01-01 00:00:05.560  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering flush()
01-01 00:00:05.561  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: flush() completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.561  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving flush()
01-01 00:00:05.561  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering serviceFlush()
01-01 00:00:05.561  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: serviceFlush() completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.561  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving serviceFlush()
01-01 00:00:05.561  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering listNetworks()
01-01 00:00:05.562  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: listNetworks() completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.562  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving listNetworks() with result = []
01-01 00:00:05.562  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: entering saveConfig()
01-01 00:00:05.569  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: saveConfig() completed successfully.
01-01 00:00:05.569  1073  1676 D SupplicantP2pIfaceHal: leaving saveConfig()
01-01 00:00:06.108  1073  1834 D WificondControl: Scan result ready event
01-01 00:00:06.113  1073  1637 W WifiConfigManager: Looking up network with invalid networkId -1
```

Still no luck. Don't know what else I can do at this point but not giving up just yet.

Comment: Do you know about https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy?

Comment: scrcpy looks quite interesting. I'll give it a go and report back here.

Comment: Thank you @Zulakis. `scrcpy` is working perfect and I couldn't be happier. I've managed to connect to Wifi normally and can resume my experimentation.

Comment: You're welcome! It's a great project :-)

Answer (score 1):

`svc wifi enable|disable` should work if it's only about turning WiFi ON and OFF. Or you can use `setWifiEnabled` method directly by calling service `wifi`. On Android 8.1 its code (order) is [`24`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/IWifiManager.aidl#99), so you can do from `adb shell`:

```
~$ service call wifi s16 null i32 1    # Trun WiFi ON
~$ service call wifi s16 null i32 0    # Trun WiFi OFF
```

But since you also need to add new network to connect, it becomes difficult to go through Android APIs from commandline.

### CONNECTING TO WIFI FROM COMMANDLINE:

Another approach is to use `wpa_supplicant` (and optionally `wpa_cli`) directly from CLI, don't rely on pre-generated `WifiConfigStore.xml` or `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

The following script includes the simple steps:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

IFACE=wlan0                 # WiFi interface name
SSID=abcxyz                 # WiFi network name
PSK=foobarfoobar            # WiFi network password
DIR=/data/local/tmp/WIFI    # temporary directory
mkdir -p $DIR

if [ "$1" = stop ]
then
    pkill wpa_supplicant
    ip ru del lookup main
    ip r f table main
    ip a f dev $IFACE
    rm -rf $DIR
    ndc resolver setnetdns 0 '' 0.0.0.0
    exit
fi

# set interface up, add rule to lookup into 'main' table
svc wifi disable
for i in /sys/class/net/*; do ip link set down dev $(basename $i); done
ip link set dev lo up
ip link set dev $IFACE up
ip rule add lookup main

# destroy set network  if any
ndc network default set 0

# create configuration file
<<-CONF cat >$DIR/wpa_supplicant.conf
    network={
        ssid="$SSID"
        psk="$PSK"
        scan_ssid=1
    }
CONF

# scan WiFi and connect to access point
wpa_supplicant -B -i $IFACE -c $DIR/wpa_supplicant.conf
until iw dev $IFACE link | grep -q '^Connected to'; do sleep 1; done

# create 'udhcpc' script
<<-'SCRIPT' cat >$DIR/udhcpc_default.script
#!/system/bin/sh

[ "$1" = bound ] || exit 0

# set IP address, add gateway route and set DNS
ip address add $ip/$mask dev $interface
ip route add default via $router dev $interface
ndc resolver setnetdns 0 '' $dns
SCRIPT

# start DHCP client to obtain IP from server
chmod 0755 $DIR/udhcpc_default.script
busybox udhcpc -v -f -q -i $IFACE -s $DIR/udhcpc_default.script
```

<sup>* Omit the DHCP part if you want to set IP, route and DNS manually.

* I use my own built `wpa_supplicant` [binary](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=6006931924117931169). `udhcpc` is a busybox applet, `ip`, `iw` and `ndc` are part of stock Android.

* For further options see [`wpa_supplicant.conf`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) and [`udhcpc` samples](https://github.com/armcc/udhcp/tree/master/samples).</sup>

**DNS:**

Apps built with Android SDK depend on Bionic libc resolver for DNS queries, so we need to [set DNS servers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r1/server/CommandListener.cpp#641) through native APIs. But still the Java network stack is down, so some apps depending on Android APIs may not behave normally. Programs linked against other C libraries may require `resolv.conf` to exist. See details in [How to configure DNS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526) and [How does Android OS do DNS name resolution?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218209/218526)

**WIFI DRIVER AND FIRMWARE:**

Another problem could be to load WiFi in-kernel driver (as module) and firmware on boot. This is handled by vendor specific `wcnss_service` which runs in combination with `android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service` HAL. For instance on my device with *Qualcomm Atheros Prima* WLAN module the service loads firmware ([`WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini`](https://github.com/franciscofranco/mido/blob/2d9cdc3b435f97daaa6e73f862eb6af151bf0f6f/drivers/staging/prima/CORE/VOSS/inc/wlan_hdd_misc.h#L34) and related `WCNSS_*`) files from `/vendor/firmware/wlan/prima/` or `/persist`.

Once you turn on WiFi after boot, all services are started (including `wificond`) and firmware is loaded. You can check using `rfkill` or `iw phy` commands or directly from `/sys/class/rfkill`. To manually load driver:

```
~# echo -n sta >/sys/module/wlan/parameters/fwpath
```

Some more details can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/libwifi_hal/wifi_hal_common.cpp), [here](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/WiFi) and [here](https://github.com/postmarketOS/pmbootstrap/issues/373).

When loading driver/firmware WiFi interface should already be created. Check using `iw dev` or `ip link`. Or you can manually create:

```
~# iw $(busybox rfkill -no device list wifi) interface add $IFACE type managed
```