# How to get IP address from DHCP running on WiFi AP using adb shell?

Tags: adb, networking, dhcp

I am connecting to my WiFi network from adb shell using the following command:

```
iw dev wlan1 connect -w WiFi-AP
```

There is a DHCP server running on the AP as well, but whenever I try to get IP address using `dhclient -v wlan1`, I get the following error:

```
sh: dhclient: not found
```

Is there a way to install dhclient on Android 8.1, or is there any other way to request IP address from the DHCP server over a wlan interface?

Comment: Android used `dhcpcd` up to Lollipop (or KitKat?). Now the client runs as a service inside Java runtime. No native tool available. You can build a static DHCP client binary from source.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Any pointers on how to start with that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Building `dhcpcd`](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/dhcpcd.html) isn't that much complicated, but it won't be of any use. Linux distributions have simpler network configuration, usually use `main` routing table and `/etc/resolv.conf` for DNS. Android has a dynamic routing policy, containing scores of rules and routes, continuously updated by `netd` with network changes. Plus Android's Bionic libc doesn't use `/etc/resolv.conf`. So even if `dhcpcd` gets you an IP and DNS nameserver from DHCP server, you still have to manually configure routing, NATing, forwarding etc.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: I have tried to use udhcpc from busybox and when I use it, it returns an IP address from DHCP, but doesn't assign it to the interface. Using some bash scripting, I can extract IP and assign manually to the interface. Did you mean the same by manually configuring?

Comment: By manual configuration I mean IP address + rule + route + DNS + iptables rules (if any required). If this WiFi is the only network you are connecting to, then route auto added to `main` table may work.

Comment: Answered here: [Connecting to WiFi via ADB Shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200285/connecting-to-wifi-via-adb-shell)