# How to remove the android OS version from the DHCP request?

Tags: dhcp

When my phone connects to my home WiFi network, it sends DHCP request in order to get an IP address. It looks like the following:

```
22:50:53.743535 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from a0:39:f7:5f:c0:45, length 300, xid 0xddd7abec, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address a0:39:f7:5f:c0:45
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether a0:39:f7:5f:c0:45
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1500
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 18: "android-dhcp-7.1.2"
            Hostname Option 12, length 9: "localhost"
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 10:
              Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server, Domain-Name
              MTU, BR, Lease-Time, RN
              RB, Vendor-Option
```

As you can see, there's `Vendor-Class Option 60, length 18: "android-dhcp-7.1.2"` which contains the OS version. Is there a way to remove this from the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [hard-coded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-7.1.2_r1/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpPacket.java#617) in Java DhcpClient:

```
...
    private String getVendorId() {
        if (testOverrideVendorId != null) return testOverrideVendorId;
        return "android-dhcp-" + Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    }
...
```

So the only way is to rebuild your ROM with modified source code. Or use a different DHCP client from command-line. For reference: [Connecting to WiFi via ADB Shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219548/218526).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extender. My Android comes in the through a TP link extender as:

```
Vendor-Class Option 60, length 12: "udhcp 1.22.1"
```

Probably not want you want, but a possibility.