# Internet access via external Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: wi-fi

Good afternoon, colleagues.

There is:

1. Samsung S7, LineageOS 15.1, root, terminal, kalinethunter, drivers for AR9271 in kernel;
2. WIFI USB adapter Alfa atheros AR9271;
3. USB-miniUSB cable.

Required:
Internet access by a browser, not through the built-in wifi of the smartphone (wlan0), but through the external one (wlan1).

Tried:

1. turn on wifi in the smartphone settings;
2. delete the memorized network in the wifi settings (so that the smartphone does not automatically connect anywhere via wlan0);
3. in the terminal:

- sudo ifconig wlan1 up (in any, kalinethunter, androidsu)
- wpa_supplicant -i wlan1 -c / etc / wpa_supplicant / wpa_supplicant-wlan1 / conf (only in kalinethunter terminal, androidsu gives wpa_supplicant not found)
- dhclient wlan1 (only in kalinethunter terminal, androidsu displays dhclient not found).

after that pass successfully:

1. from the terminal kalinethunter ping 8.8.8.8 and ping google.com;
2. from the androidsu terminal - ping 8.8.8.8 (if I add ip google.com to system/etc/hosts, then ping google.com also work);

But browsers (firefox, chrome) do not see the network. How can I go to the Internet with a browser (firefox, chrome) through wlan1, can you have ideas?

Comment: See my answer to [Connecting to WiFi via ADB Shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219548/218526). Also related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526