# Connecting external wifi adapter to android 6

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow

This question may be asked before but I couldn't find a working answer so I will ask again.
I got a Android 6 device which has root permissions. But its kernel is the stock one. I want to connect a cheap wifi adapter that doesn't support monitor mode (now don't write that I use it for cracking/hacking and etc.) to my phone. I also have chroot environment in case of compiling driver. How can I use that usb adapter to share my connection at least from chroot???

Now about why I use it: The router in class that is next to us has very short wifi range and it almost doesn't come until our class(Don't worry,we got their permissions) so,I want to use my phone to extend the range and be able to use that network in my class.(From other devices)

What I tried until now:

1. Sharing WiFi on same interface using [Create_AP](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).
   Result: It created a AP but clients couldn't get connection even though I could. And WiFi interface kinda hard blocked and didn't work until I rebooted phone.
2. WiFi tethers for Android
   Result: They didn't work as well.

EDIT 1: I guess I got some progress. Check out https://pastebin.com/jQqHX5Ms

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526). Don't say it's about Ethernet. It's applicable to WiFi adapters as well.

Comment: [Connecting to WiFi via ADB Shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219548/218526)

Comment: @Irfan Latif , it will take a year to understand everything  written in posts(cuz I have no experience with Android(WHYTF IT DOESNT USE REGULAR DEBIAN)) so I cant say it worked or not in near future

Comment: Thanks anyways. I will try to do it.

Comment: @IrfanLatif , please,check this note: https://pastebin.com/jQqHX5Ms

Comment: @IrfanLatif I used PPP Widget 3 instead of scripts there,is it okay? And btw it returned no modem response. Ig it is due that I don't have its module for my kernel(mt7601U.ko). How can I compile it specificly for my device?? I have cross compiler with parameters but it needs kernel build too so where and how can I find it?

Comment: @IrfanLatif , please check this XDA post. I gave more details there: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-cross-compile-wifi-drivers-for-android.4370231

Comment: And please,respond if u saw any of these

Comment: Yes I did see your comments. But I'm really sorry I don't have time to go with you on the long troubleshooting journey. I hope you'll find better answers than mine.

Comment: @IrfanLatif ,Okay..  Thanks for guides at least. I will try my best to solve it